# jquery replace full document content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax response, that returns the full html of a webpage, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- head content -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- body content -->
  </body>
</html>
```

So I want all of this replacing the document of my calling page after the ajax call.
How do I do this?

Comment: I can't get that to work. The solution in that topic does not replace my HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
document.open();
document.write(myString);
document.close();
```

You can also try:

```
    var startHead = myString.indexOf("<head>");
    var endHead = myString.indexOf("</head>");        
    var headString = myString.substring(startHead+6,endHead);

    var startBody = myString.indexOf("<body>");
    var endBody = myString.indexOf("</body>");
    var bodyString = myString.substring(startBody+6,endBody);

    jQuery('head').html(headString);
    jQuery('body').html(bodyString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $('html').replaceWith(myString);
```

Comment: Note that this replaces the jQuery object as well, so if you're keeping references you need to update them. courtesy @Aram Kocharyan

Answer (score 0):

> I have an ajax response, that returns the full html of a webpage

If that's the case, why not just redirect to that page?

```
window.location.href = your_url;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
document.write(xmlhttp.responseText); // using AJAX
```